# I can't download the information I need from the website

Tags: python, html, web

I would like to download the websites of each product to connect to them but I am not able to connect to the web. For example if I had the html it would be great. When I download the page I can see that inside it appears a web similar to this for each compound but I can't download it:  a href="https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/product/aldrich/416665"
Thanks in advance

For example, when I run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=' https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/products/materials-science/biomedical-materials/polymerization-tools?country=GB&language=en&cmsRoute=products&cmsRoute=materials-science&cmsRoute=biomedical-materials&cmsRoute=polymerization-tools&page=1%22'

soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
print(soup)
```

I cannot see the product data.

Comment: The website uses JavaScript to generate the content dynamically. You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser.

Comment: as per the above:  Max retries exceeded with url,  Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a webdriver to emulate browsing, or you can call the graphql api like so:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'x-gql-country': 'US',
    'x-gql-access-token': '7422fb01-fe49-11ec-b208-a93cbb385750',
    'x-gql-guid': 'GA1.2.1984313165.1657235201',
    'x-gql-language': 'en',
    'x-gql-operation-name': 'CategoryProductSearch',
    'Origin': 'https://www.sigmaaldrich.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Referer': 'https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/products/materials-science/biomedical-materials/polymerization-tools?country=GB&language=en&cmsRoute=products&cmsRoute=materials-science&cmsRoute=biomedical-materials&cmsRoute=polymerization-tools&page=1%22%27',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

json_data = {
    'operationName': 'CategoryProductSearch',
    'variables': {
        'searchTerm': None,
        'page': 1,
        'perPage': 20,
        'sort': 'relevance',
        'selectedFacets': [
            {
                'key': 'facet_web_product_area',
                'options': [
                    'S281',
                ],
            },
        ],
        'facetSet': [
            'facet_product_category',
            'facet_web_polymer_arch_functionality',
            'facet_web_polymer_arch_shape',
            'facet_fwght',
            'facet_web_greener_alternative_principles',
            'facet_web_markush-class',
            'facet_web_markush-group',
            'facet_melting_point',
            'facet_physical_form',
            'facet_web_react_suitability_reagent_type',
            'facet_brand',
        ],
    },
    'query': 'query CategoryProductSearch($searchTerm: String, $page: Int!, $perPage: Int!, $sort: Sort, $selectedFacets: [FacetInput!], $facetSet: [String]) {\n  getProductSearchResults(input: {searchTerm: $searchTerm, pagination: {page: $page, perPage: $perPage}, sort: $sort, group: product, facets: $selectedFacets, facetSet: $facetSet}) {\n    ...CategoryProductSearchFields\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment CategoryProductSearchFields on ProductSearchResults {\n  metadata {\n    itemCount\n    page\n    perPage\n    numPages\n    __typename\n  }\n  items {\n    ... on Product {\n      ...CategorySubstanceProductFields\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  facets {\n    key\n    numToDisplay\n    isHidden\n    isCollapsed\n    multiSelect\n    prefix\n    options {\n      value\n      count\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment CategorySubstanceProductFields on Product {\n  name\n  productNumber\n  productKey\n  isMarketplace\n  marketplaceOfferId\n  marketplaceSellerId\n  attributes {\n    key\n    label\n    values\n    __typename\n  }\n  brand {\n    key\n    erpKey\n    name\n    color\n    __typename\n  }\n  images {\n    altText\n    smallUrl\n    mediumUrl\n    largeUrl\n    __typename\n  }\n  description\n  paMessage\n  __typename\n}\n',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/api', headers=headers, json=json_data)
data = response.json()
```

You may not need all of the header keys, some may not longer be valid after a period of time. But this will give you a data object with what you need.

Once you have the links to compound:
There may be a better way to do this...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/o7805', headers=headers)
sp = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
#find the data script
str_data = sp.find('script',{'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}).text
#assign values so eval works correctly
false = False
true = True
null = None
#evaluate the string to python dict
d = eval(str_data)
#take what you need
cas = d['props']['pageProps']['data']['getProductDetail']['casNumber']
attrs = d['props']['pageProps']['data']['getProductDetail']['attributes']
smiles = [attr_d['values'] for attr_d in attrs if attr_d['key']=='smiles string']

print(cas,smiles)
```

output:

```
112-90-3 [['[H]\\C(CCCCCCCC)=C(/[H])CCCCCCCCN']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have been trying these days to get the CAS numbers of each molecule and the SMILES string but cannot. Do you know how I could do it for each compound. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to call the page for each compound.